# Investing in cryptocurrency. Is there an issue?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, money

Is there a problem with investing in a digital currency and letting it sit on Shabbat and holidays? It's fairly volatile and can increase or decrease greatly in value. So I'm wondering if these potential gains and losses occurring during holy days can pose a halachic problem, even if you're not buying or selling on those days.

Is there a difference between this and buying a particular paper currency, hoping it will appreciate in value faster than another?

Some well known cryptocurrencies include Bitcoin and Ethereum.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I read this correctly, you're not asking about any particular technical actions, but just about the fact that these are securities whose value is particularly volatile. Is that right?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Yes, I'm wondering if the fact that their value will change during holy days will mean that holding onto them will be a desecration of Shabbat and so on.

Comment: I do not know too much about cryptocurrencies but most currencies (or investments) can gain or lose value during a Holy Day. Would bitcoin be different due to the factors that influence its value?

Comment: Another potential concern: BTC is so often (primarily?) used as payment on the dark web for forbidden activities (illicit drugs, child pornography, ransomware payments, etc.) While cash is also used for bad things in the physical world, BTC seems to be used primarily for illicit transactions thanks to its digital, mostly-anonymous nature.

Comment: Why should it be different than gold (or flour) which also changes value?

Comment: I would think the only possible problem is in regard to דבר שלא בא לעולם, since bitcoins aren't physical items (though I assume the same issue would be applicable to investing in general)